# Proving that if $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$ then $\mathbf{A}$ has a zero determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$\mathbf{A}$  is a square matrix of order $n\times n$, $\mathbf{1}$  is the column vector that has all elements are $1$, $\mathbf{0}$  is the column vector that has all elements are zero.

I encounter this problem in a book of matrix algebra and haven't been able to find the solution to it yet. Could anyone please help me on this?

Sorry this is my first post on the site (and also my first post asking for solutions relating to mathematics so there might be many issues in wording and format of notations).

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To format mathematics, have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting only in the title.

Comment: Thank you @P.Senden for your link!

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the determinat directly. Let $c_1 , \ldots , c_n$ be the columns of $A$:
$$detA = det(c_1\; c_2 \; \ldots \; c_n) = det(c_1+c_2+\ldots + c_n \; c_2\; \cdots \; c_n)  \stackrel{A\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{0}}{=} det(\mathbf{0} \; c_2 \;\ldots c_n) = 0 $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Your solution is direct, simple and really easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is non-singular, then the system $Ax=0$ only has the trivial solution.

In this case, you have found a non-trivial solution, hence it must be singular.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$$

The terms of  the column vector,  $$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{1}$$ are simply row sums of matrix $ \mathbf{A}$

$$ a_{11} +a_{12} +... a_{1n}=0$$

$$ a_{21} +a_{22} +... a_{2n}=0\\.\\.\\.$$

$$ a_{n1} +a_{n2} +... a_{nn}=0$$

Thus the columns of $ \mathbf{A}$ are linearly dependent.

Which results  in $$ \det  \mathbf{A}=0$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I haven't come to the section for linear dependency yet but your solution is helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you happen to be allowed to use eigenvalues: $$A\,\boldsymbol{1}_n =\boldsymbol{0}_n =0\cdot\boldsymbol{1}_n \implies \text{$0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$} \implies \det(A)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $A$ having a non-zero determinant is equivalent to a great many things. Among a few are:

- The system $Ax = b$ has a unique solution for all $b$.
- The system $Ax = 0$ has only one solution: $x = 0$.
- The scalar $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Take your pick! They all imply the above.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$$

We also have  $$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}$$

That is the system in   $$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{0}$$ has more than one solution.

This happens only if $\det \mathbf{A}=0$

Comment: Thank you so much @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani for your answers! I have come to the section for linear dependence and understood your previous answer as well as this one :)

Comment: @Sophil  Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Another direct proof (besides trancelocation's): multiply both sides of $0=A\mathbf1$ by $\operatorname{adj}(A)$. Then $0=\operatorname{adj}(A)A\mathbf1=\det(A)I\mathbf1=\det(A)\mathbf1$. Comparing both sides entrywise, we get $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: Thank you @user1551 for your answer! I hadn't learned about inverse matrices when I posted the question but I have just learned it now so I understand your solution. Thanks so much for your help!